# start pm2 processes on system boot using a shell script

Tags: shell, pm2

I was looking on how to write a **SHELL** script that:

1. Change the working directory to directory `path/to/dir/A`
2. Then get's all the `".js"` files in directory `path/to/dir/A/X`
3. And iterates over them all one by one with this command `"pm2 start {files in directory A}"`

I'm new to SHELL scripting so any help is welcome.
Just to add, those files are pm2 config files to start different processes. Each process has its own file. Thus the need to iterate over all of them.

Comment: What's directory `X`? What do you mean by "get" the `.js` files? Copy them to `A`?

Comment: I still don't get it. What does step 2 do exactly?

Comment: the .js files are in their own directory inside directory A. step 2 and 3 are the same

Comment: So you want to `cd` into `A`, then loop over the files in `A/X/*.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `X` is in the question, but seeing how you've accepted an answer that ignores `X`, here is my solution:

```
for fname in /path/to/A/*.js; do
    pm2 start "$fname"
done
```

This simply loops over a glob expanding to all `.js` files in `A` and runs `pm2 start` on them.

---

In case the process *needs* to be started from a specific directory, you do have to `cd` into it. After edits to the question:

```
cd /path/to/A
for fname in X/*.js; do
    pm2 start "$fname"
done
```

Comment: The so edited after I had accepted the ans. The original ans was correct and solved my issue, even though it didn't consider best practices

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries I don't think the edit changes anything functionally, it just makes the directory a parameter.

Comment: What if the path has spaces?

Comment: Quote it: `for fname in '/path/has space/to/A/'*.js`

Comment: instead of `cd` is there any way to change the working directory of `pm2` ?

Comment: This seems to be discussed in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/96). [This comment](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/96#issuecomment-297997456) says to use the `CWD` option in `ecosystem.config.js`, maybe that works? I'm not familiar with PM2 at all.

Comment: that is for the apps that are being initialised by PM2, what if i want to change the working directory for the whole bash script to a certain folder

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries I've added a second version that changes directory first and uses the `X` directory.

Comment: that's what i wanted. Let me test it in a bit. just to confirm, the working directory for PM2 will now be A? after i cd into it? irrespective of where the shell script is called from?

Comment: Yes, because you `cd` to `/path/to/A` (note the leading `/`), an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

```
DIR="A"
cd "$DIR";
ls "$DIR/*.js" >/tmp/list
(while read f; do
pm2 start "$DIR/$f"
done) </tmp/list
rm /tmp/list
```

Comment: Thanks. tho' it's supposed to get the ".js" files from directory X. Will accept after you edit your ans.

Comment: I don't think this works, and it doesn't follow best practices. It doesn't work because `*.js` is quoted, so it looks for a file literally called `*.js`. Then, you don't need a temp file. When reading line by line, you should use `IFS= read -r` to avoid backslash interpretation and whitespace mangling. Why is the `while` loop in a subshell? You shouldn't programmatically process the output of `ls`.

Comment: Also, since you `cd` into `A`, when you call `pm2 start "$DIR/$f"` (a relative path), `pm2` will see the path `/path/to/A/A/$f`. I don't see how this ever worked.